# GearVR in AFrame - seems to just map the web frame onto a sphere

Tags: aframe, gear-vr

Running into an issue with A-Frame 0.3.0 running in GearVR on the Samsung Internet app.

When it loads it displays the A-Frame scene on a card hovering in space like an ordinary stationary web page - the content in the web page rotates with head tracking, but the card remains stationary in space.

When I click on the various 360/180 display modes, the image of the flat web page appears to simply map to a sphere and responds loosely to head rotation - there are swirly patterns at the poles so I'm pretty sure it's just a 2D mapping of the web page. Like it's trying to display it as a 360 video.

Is there a hidden setting? I've enabled WebVR in the Samsung browser. Or is there a directive I need to include in A-Frame? The scene runs fine in cardboard through chrome on android.  thx

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Betts from Slack said:

> You have to type 'internet://webvr-enable' into the address bar to enable it.

Here is the documentation by Samsung: http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000270L where it says:

> To enable WebVR visit the internet://webvr-enable URL in the Samsung Internet for GearVR browser (visit internet://webvr-disable to disable WebVR support).

Comment: As indicated I already enabled it by typing that into the browser, but maybe I made a mistake.  There was an indication that it was enabled. Are there more steps or options?

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Will ask some Samsung folks.

Answer (score 1):

ngokevin's answer is correct, you have to enable. If that done correctly, a working demo using 1.0 API will be able to go into correct mode. Note that can't access correct 'mode' using the fullscreen mode options meant for VR/360 video formats. Try https://toji.github.io/webvr-samples/03-vr-presentation.html If this example doesn't work then have not enabled. If this runs but another page doesn't it would be an issue specific to that page and WebVR API usage.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the test page -it loads and does the right thing. My scene goes into a split (L/R) screen mapped to a card that is stuck in space and doesn't move with head tracking. So definitely something bad on my end. I'll compare them and figure out what I'm doing or not doing :) Thanks again.

Comment: The link that you pointed me to works, but it's not an A-Frame example - it's a straight WebVR example - so WebVR is enabled. Other A-Frame pages exhibit the same behavior as my page - the content is displayed on a card and either that floats in a locked position in space or can be mapped like a 360 video onto a spherical projection. So there's still something wrong.

Comment: The problem was in using A-Frame 0.2.0 - the scene behaves properly in GearVR now, except that no longer displays textures and gives a "RENDER WARNING: Render count or primcount is 0." - but that's a different issue requiring a different Question.

Comment: the no textures, white renders, has to do with the material and obj-loader components being order dependent - it's flipped for chrome and safari vs firefox. is a known bug. Is not an issue with Gear or Samsung Internet - aside from that being chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that webvr support in Gear VR is still experimental and really doesn't work very well yet.

For me the Gear VR is extremely jerky and makes you dizzy when looking around and the quality just isn't very good on the sky images.

I'm using a new Gear 360 camera to take my sky images and when I look at them through the regular Gear VR 360 photo viewer app they look awesome but once you go into webvr and look at those same images they're really really blurry.

Hopefully Gear VR can get the kinks worked out soon and hopefully just replaces that stupid Samsung browser with the new Oculus Carmel browser so these webvr apps will work correctly.